# Validating an unknown set of items with WTForms

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I have a form that looks something like this:

```
<form method="post">
    <input id="1" name="people" type="checkbox" value="1"/>
    <label for="1">Paul</label>

    <input id="2" name="people" type="checkbox" value="2"/>
    <label for="2">Elizabeth</label>

    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

When submitting this form, I want to validate that the user has checked at least one person. Note that I don't want to use `name"person-0"` and `name="person-1"`, I actually want to use `name="people"` as the name of my objects.

I'll create my form using something like this...

```
class MyForm(Form):
    some_field = fields.TextField(u'Some Field', [validators.required()])
    some_option = fields.BooleanField(u'Some Option')
    people = # What to put here?
```

So, what type of field can I use for the 'people' field?

I don't think I can use FieldList, since that will expect the names to be `person-0` and `person-1` rather than `people`, which I don't want. I can't use SelectMultipleField because that seems to expect a list of choices, and I don't know the list of choices (it is dynamically given to me by a 3rd party).

I'm only using the form for validation of the resulting HTML post data, not rendering the HTML, so no worries there.

I'm going to post what I've done as an answer, which is to use a custom field. But I was wondering if there was some way to do this in wtforms using the built-in fields.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I have so far ended up doing:

I create my own field called "ListField"...

```
class ListField(Field):
    def process_formdata(self, valuelist):
        self.data = valuelist
```

Then I can use it like the following:

```
class MyForm(Form):
    some_field = fields.TextField(u'Some Field', [validators.required()])
    some_option = fields.BooleanField(u'Some Option')
    people = ListField()

    def validate_people(self, field):
        if len(field.data) == 0:
            raise ValidationError('Must select at least one person')
```

This works for now, but I'm not sure if there is a way to do this with the built-in fields and validators.